# rails sunspot searchable enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

How to make enum in rails searchable with sunspot?

enum type: [ :restaurant, :travel, :hotel ]

```
searchable do
    text :name, :boost => 5
    text :description
    integer :type
    time :created_at
end
```

my controller:

```
@search = Product.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
```

still no results, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the searchable field definition from an integer to a string, and use `with(:field, params[:search_query])`.

model:

```
searchable do
  string :enum_field
end
```

controller:

```
@search = Product.search do
  with(enum_field: params[:search_query])
end
```

EDIT:  Also, it just occurred to me that you might need to rename your enum column, as ActiveRecord uses `type` to signify Single Table Inheritance.